# NHibernate Fluently Exception - Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate, .net-4.5

It is impossible for me to pass on all the information necessary to solve this problem.

I need tips, solutions to similar problems ... that kind of thing.

When I solve it, I mark the answer that helped me solve the problem and post how it was done.

Thanks to all who contribute any information.

---

Only a few columns are mapped and `Id` are set as "PK".
I don't have a clue about what happeing.

- I try to remove Nullabe from `ID` column, same problem
- Change the entire project to work with `Decimal` not `Decimal?`, same problem
- Found nothing about this on google

It's like someone on NHibernate forget to check `IsDbNull()` before reflection.

### CLASS

```cs
public class BaseMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : IEntity
{
    public BaseMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();
    }
}

public class UsuarioMap : BaseMap<Usuario>
{
    public UsuarioMap()
    {
        //Indica qual a tabela deve ser utilizada.
        Table("FUNCIONARIO");
        Map(x => x.CodigoReduzido, "FUN_CODIGO");
        Map(x => x.CodPerfilBiomeek, "PER_CODIGO");
        Map(x => x.Local, "LOC_CODIGO");
        Map(x => x.Nome, "FUN_NOME");
        Map(x => x.DataInclusao, "FUN_DT_INC");
        Map(x => x.UsuarioInclusao, "FUN_FUN_INC");
    }
}
```

### TABLE

[image]

### Exception

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
   at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.OutputParamReturningDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand insert, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, SqlCommandInfo sql, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrReplicate(Object entity, EntityKey key, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.PerformSave(Object entity, Object id, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean useIdentityColumn, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A disabled trigger is the cause of the problem

```cs
Id(x => x.Id, "ID").GeneratedBy.TriggerIdentity();
```

After the *INSERT* the disabled trigger do not generate ID and "ID" column return with **DbNull** value.

[image]